# Invoke method based on list

Tags: scala, reflection

I have object in scala, where I have defined functions. I have Seq where all the functions are listed as the elements as below:

```
object ABC {

  def abc(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a+b
  def pqr(p: Int, q: Int): Int = p - q
  val listFunction: Seq[(Int, Int) => Int] = Seq(abc, pqr)


}
```

Now, I want to call the list which I defined as string and execute all the functions inside it, by taking the parameters. Similar to the below:

```
val listName = "listFunction"
val method = example.ABC.getClass.getMethod(listName,1,2)
```

Can someone help me, how to invoke the listFunction list and execute all the functions inside it.

Comment: Why do you need a string?

Answer (score 1):

To call the methods do this:

```
val result: Seq[Int] = ABC.listFunction.map(_(1, 2))
```

This calls each function in turn and puts the result in a new `Seq`.

If you want multiple lists indexed by name, use a `Map` like this:

```
object ABC {
  def abc(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a+b
  def pqr(p: Int, q: Int): Int = p - q

  private val functions = Map(
    "listFunction" -> Seq(abc _, pqr _),
    "listReverse" ->  Seq(pqr _, abc _),
  )
  def apply(name: String) = functions(name)
}

val listName = "listFunction"
val result: Seq[Int] = ABC(listName).map(_(1, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Here listFunction I'm passing as string. Like
val functionName = "listFunction" . The above code ABC.functionName.map(_(1,2)) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val listName = "listFunction"
example.ABC.getClass.getMethod(listName).invoke(example.ABC).asInstanceOf[Seq[(Int, Int) => Int]].map(_.apply(1, 2)) // List(3, -1)
```

Comment: @swati https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eyy6FutFS66awXwGLZD7kw